# is mongodb safe/secure to build mobile app in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I am newbie in meteor. I planned to develop a mobile app in meteor with existing mongodb. Is it safe/secure to build mobile app in meteor?. where database credentials will be stored, mobile or server?

Comment: You can write insecure code in the most mature of frameworks. 99.99% of the time, your code makes it insecure, not the framework/platform. The Meteor platform is as secure as any.

Answer (score 1):

The database credentials will be stored in the server. The user's login credentials will also be encrypted before being sent to the server.

Anything you want to be server-side only you should put under your /server directory. Everything else is potentially visible client-side.

Comment: where temple will be stored. server or App? sorry if my question is wrong

Comment: @BlueBells templates are stored on client side.

Answer (score 1):

to avoid problems you have to take care of two default settings which are active for development - but need to be switched of for production:

*By default, Meteor makes all of the data inside our database available to our users. This is convenient during development but a big security hole that needs to be plugged*.

- This default functionality is contained within an **autopublish** package. To remove it use: `meteor remove autopublish` but it also breaks and needs to be fixed.

  - The first step in fixing the application is using a Meteor.publish function inside the isServer conditional to decide what data should be available.
  - Because Meteor.publish function executes on the server, it continues to have access to all of our data. This is because code on the server is inherently trusted.
  - The second step in fixing the application is using a Meteor.subscribe function from within the isClient conditional to reference the publish function.
  - Inside the publish function, we can’t use the Meteor.userId() function. We can, however, achieve the same thing with this.userId .

*By default, it’s possible for users to insert, update, and remove data from a collection using the JavaScript Console. This is convenient for development but a big security risk for a live application.*

- The solution is to move the database-related code to the trusted environment of the server. There, users don’t have any direct control.
- To first remove the security risk, with `meteor remove insecure` -> remove the insecure package from the project. The application will become much more secure but our application will break. None of the database-related features will work.
- By using **methods**, you are able to write code that runs on the server after it’s triggered from the client. This is how to fix the application.
- To create methods, use a methods block on the server, and then trigger methods with the Meteor.call function.
- You can pass data from the Meteor.call function and into the method, allowing us to still use data from our submitted form on the server.

(Answers party copied from "Your First Meteor Application", David Turnbull)

Hope that helps to get the concept.

Michael

Comment: Thanks very mush to spend your time to explain me :)